# create Aroon Indicator in Python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, indicator, ohlc

I want to add aroon (bullish and bearish) indicator column to the data frame of stock price OHLCV. Aroon calculation is [here](https://www.investopedia.com/ask/answers/112814/what-aroon-indicator-formula-and-how-indicator-calculated.asp)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to build aroon indicator with Python pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47950466/how-to-build-aroon-indicator-with-python-pandas)

Answer (score 0):

I recommend checking out [`pandas_ta`](https://github.com/twopirllc/pandas-ta) library with over 80 indicators:

```
$ pip install pandas_ta
```

```py
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> import pandas_ta as ta
>>> pd.concat([price_ohlcv, price_ohlcv.ta.aroon()], axis=1).tail()
                            open    high    low     close   volume  AROOND_14   AROONU_14
time                            
2020-04-30 00:00:00+00:00   1.095   1.102   1.093   1.098   70879.0 57.142857   7.142857
2020-05-01 00:00:00+00:00   1.097   1.097   1.090   1.091   79412.0 50.000000   92.857143
2020-05-04 00:00:00+00:00   1.091   1.093   1.083   1.084   74476.0 42.857143   85.714286
2020-05-05 00:00:00+00:00   1.084   1.085   1.078   1.080   78846.0 35.714286   78.571429
2020-05-06 00:00:00+00:00   1.079   1.082   1.079   1.080   22443.0 28.571429   71.428571
```